# How to use jQuery variable in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

Im using a **MVC** in PHP and I have this script created in my form page to validate three text boxes. When these three text boxes contain a value my php code in my controller asks Google Map Api for the closest directions based on the input of these three fields.

In my script I have the variable "direccion" which is what I need to pass to the controller using PHP but im not sure how to accomplish this.

**Script Code (View)**:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    var direccion="";
    var flag = false;
    jQuery(".validation").change(function () {
        flag = true;
        jQuery(".validation").each(function () {
            if (jQuery(this).val().trim() == "") {
                alert("false");
                flag = false;
            }
        });
        if (flag==true) {

            var calle = jQuery("#ff_elem295").val();
            var municipio = jQuery("#id_municipio option:selected").text();
            var provincia = jQuery("#id_provincia option:selected").text();             

            direccion = calle +","+ municipio +","+ provincia;
            direccion = direccion.replace(/\s/g,'+');
            //alert(direccion);
        }       
});

jQuery.ajax({
            url: "index.php?option=com_cstudomus&controller=saloninmobiliarios&task=calcularDistancias",
            data : direccion,
            dataType : 'html'
        }).done(function(){
                var data = data;
        });
});
```

**PHP Code (Controller)**:

```
function calcularDistancias(){

    $valor = JRequest::getVar('direccion');

    $url =  'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='. $valor .'&sensor=false';

    $data = file_get_contents($url);

    $data_array = json_decode($data,true);

    $lat = $data_array[results][0][geometry][location][lat];
    $lng = $data_array[results][0][geometry][location][lng];
......
}
```

Comment: I think you need to use ajax..?

Comment: Yes, thats what I am trying to do and where I pass the variable "direccion" but im not sure how to pick this variable up using PHP and using it in my php function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`data` property in the object passed to jQuery.ajax is an object.

```
data : { direccion: direccion }
```

Then you can access the value of `direccion` in your controller as a request parameter.

Comment: He has to set `type` option to 'POST' as well if he want to pass data as `POST`

Comment: I remove the POST thing and wrote it more general

Comment: @RobinWebdev what do you refer to when you say request parameter? Like $_GET?

Comment: By default it is $_GET. 

If you want to use $_POST you have to set `type` options to `POST` like @hindmost said.

Answer (score 1):

In the `if` condition put your ajax request like

```
if(flag == true) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "index.php?option=com_cstudomus&controller=saloninmobiliarios&task=calcularDistancias",
        data : {direction : direccion},
        dataType : 'html'
    }).done(function(){
            var data = data;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition the retrieved data are missing in your code, don't forget to put data in done function :

```
.done(function(){
    var data = data;
});
```

To

```
.done(function(data){
    var data = data;
});
```